# Change module name in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a ejbModule and I want to change his name according with profile.

Is there a way that I can change the name generated in a jar, something like finalName for the artifact?

My pom:

```
<modules>
   <ejbModule>
      <groupId>grerj.sample</groupId>
      <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
   </ejbModule>
</modules>
```

I would like to have a jar with the name hsample instead of sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the [bundleName like the documentation suggested](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customizing-a-module-filename.html) which looks like this:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
           [...]
           <modules>
             <ejbModule>
               <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
               <bundleFileName>TheNameYouPrefer</bundleFileName>
             </ejbModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default name is your artifactId.

But you can define the generated name in your `pom.xml`.

Inside the `build`-tag, you can define the `finalName` like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>hsample</finalName>
</build>
```

These settings have to be done inside the `pom.xml` of your grerj.sample.sample maven module.

Comment: But I would like to define the name of the module (that will be generate as a jar).

Comment: Then you can insert these lines inside your root pom.xml

Comment: Then you can define a variable inside your profile properties and insert the this value to finalName

Comment: This will only change the name in the target folder and not the final name after an artifact is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

The module name is relevant for the module part in [portable JNDI name](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html).

It is normally the ejb-jar.jar name, but it can be overridden with ejb-jar.xml, even for annotation based ejbs.

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
    <module-name>MyModuleName</module-name>
</ejb-jar>
```

This gives a JNDI Name for an EJB in an ear like

```
java:global/myApp/MyModuleName/MyBean!my.package.MyBean
```

So Maven can well create versioned EJB Jar-Names, the JNDI name stays the same.

Comment: Note that the `ejb-jar.xml` should be placed into `src/main/resources/META-INF` of your Maven EJB-JAR project.